# OpenMP: sum reduction -- incorrect result if not using +=

Tags: openmp

I have the code as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N       10
double x[N];
int main(void)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++ i)
            x[i] = (double) i;

#pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++ i)
        {
            sum += (double) x[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%le\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is 45, which makes sense. However, if I replace `sum += (double) x[i]` with `sum = (double) x[i]`, the output is then always 43. Could anyone explain why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: assignment ( `=` ) will overwrite old value. the expression `a+=b` means 'read a, add b, and store back result in a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's happening here. I thought `sum` was copied for each ITERATION, but actually `sum` is copied for each THREAD. I have 8 threads running, so one of them has lost its initial value. Solved. Thanks for all your answers here!

Comment: Use the clause firstprivate to initialize the variable `sum` for the first thread, althought it is not necesary for a `reduction` clause.

Comment: @algui91 Why do we need it?

Comment: no, you do not need it, you would need it if you were not using `reduction`, `reduction` take cares of initializing `sum`

Answer (score 3):

If you replace `sum += (double) x[i]` by `sum = (double) x[i]`, you are not acummulating the result, hence, `sum` will store the value of the last iteration.